# download file from sftp using private key in place of password

Tags: curl, download, sftp, private-key

i want to download file from sftp using private key in place of password. i have a username and sftp login but was not able to find a command. 
I am using curl and trying it for first time. Can someone help me with the command.

Answer (score 1):

The Key options for curl are:

--key  for a private key. I believe this is for TLS SSH

--pubkey  for SFTP or SCP public key

Put a colon (:) after the username to prevent it from asking for a password when you are using keys.

Comment: where to put the sftp login?

Comment: i am using this :  curl -u username: --key my_path_to_privateKey sftp3.abc.com

Comment: --verbose might give a better view of what is going on with the connection

Comment: Remember the private key is used for your authentication while the public key verifies the server. You might need both but the verbose option should tell you where the connection is failing.

Comment: ":" is the trick. Thanks :)